# Nginx: proxy_store_access option doesn't seem to work

Tags: configuration, nginx, http-proxy

I'm using proxy_pass to handle file uploading via nginx for a Rails app, and it's working fine, , except for the file permissions.  Here's the current config block:

```
location ~ ^my_filename_regex$ {

  limit_except POST { deny all; }
  client_body_temp_path      /path/to/app/tmp;
  client_body_in_file_only   on;
  client_body_buffer_size    128K;
  client_max_body_size       1000M;

  # try_files $uri @slow-rails;
  proxy_pass                 http://elrs;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file; 
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_redirect             off;

  # might not need?
  proxy_read_timeout         3m;
}
```

`elrs` is an upstream i have defined to just point to my local rails server (127.0.0.1:3000).

The file comes through, and is saved in a tmp location, which i read from `request.headers['X-FILE']`: so far, so good.

The problem is that the file comes in owned by a different user (www-data, which is what nginx runs under), and doesn't have group read, so i can't get at it without doing a `sudo chmod` on it in my rails app, which is proving quite fragile and unreliable.

```
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 1430753 Feb 23 13:36 /path/to/app/tmp/0057375433
```

Based on this page: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass 
i've added this option

```
      proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
```

which i'd thought would set it to `-rw-rw-r--`, which is fine for my purposes.  However, after restarting nginx and trying again, it's still coming through just with `-rw-------`.  The new option doesn't seem to work, in other words.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong, or how i can diagnose the problem?  I'm using Nginx v 1.9.7.

I'm not 100% sure that i do have the ngx_http_proxy_module installed: i'd assumed that if i didn't then the proxy_pass stuff would all just completely fail, but maybe that's not the case.  How can i test whether it has this module?

thanks, Max

EDIT: I also just noticed, while experimenting with using a different folder to write the temp file into, that ngnix is taking ownership of that folder too:  ie, before doing the file upload the folder was owned by `max:max` and now it's owned by `www-data:max`.  I just mention this in case it's relevant.

Comment: Are you sure that nginx is responsible for creating the file and not your rails app? `proxy_store_access` seems to be related to `proxy_store`.

Comment: It's definitely nginx - the file appears on the server in the location specified in the nginx config, and if i change this then it appears in the new location next time i do an upload.  The rails app just reads the file location out of the request header, where nginx has written it.

Comment: Oh, but do you mean that i may need to set `proxy_store on;` as well?  That sounds plausible.  I'm a bit hazy on the difference between `proxy_pass` and `proxy_store` to be honest.

Comment: No, the `xxx_store` directives all relate to storing the response (and not the client request body). I cannot see how you specify permissions for `client_body_temp_path`.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to recompile nginx :( after editing `src/os/unix/ngx_files.c` and changing the file creation mask in `ngx_open_tempfile` from `0600` to `0660` (or whatever perms you require).

Changing the umask in the nginx init script doesn't help because of that `0600` value.

There's no `user:`, `group:` or `other:` configuration setting available for `client_body_temp_path` like there is for the proxy module.

Even though the `ngx_open_tempfile` function reads the `access` variable that might otherwise be set to something other than `0600` by calling `ngx_conf_set_access_slot` like it is for these modules:

```
src/http/modules/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.c
171:      ngx_conf_set_access_slot,

src/http/modules/ngx_http_dav_module.c
102:      ngx_conf_set_access_slot,

src/http/modules/ngx_http_scgi_module.c
111:      ngx_conf_set_access_slot,

src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c
254:      ngx_conf_set_access_slot,

src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c
291:      ngx_conf_set_access_slot,
```

it's not available for the client code which is part of nginx core. Hence the need for the re-compile.

As well as updating the `0600` to `0660` you'll need to `chgrp your_app_server_group` the `client_body_temp_path` directory to the group that your app belongs to, and then also setgid on it (`chmod g+s your_app_server_group`), so files written into it by nginx are owned by that group.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I was having a similar issue. My goal was to let Nginx handle the upload and then pass it to a Django application. Even if something went wrong in the Django app I still wanted the upload to succeed and get stored to disk.

@jaygooby is right, you can't instruct Nginx to write the file under a different user, group or permissions without changing the source code.

However you can use [bindfs](http://bindfs.org) to create an extra mount-point that points to the `client_body_temp_path` folder.

**Install BindFS**
Under Ubuntu: `apt-get install bindfs`
If you are using a different OS, have a look at the [bindfs](http://bindfs.org) website.

**Create the folders**
Make sure that the folders exist. Assign the proper ownership and permissions.

```
mkdir /var/local/incoming
mkdir /var/local/processing
```

I point `client_body_temp_path` to the `incoming` folder. The `processing` folder is going to act like an automatic mirror that will provide access to the files with the proper ownership and permissions.

**Configure your mount-point**
Add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`, so that it automatically mounts the folder after a reboot. You can do a quick `sudo mount -a` to reload your `fstab`.

```
/var/local/incoming /var/local/processing
fuse.bindfs force-user=myUser,force-group=myGroup,perms=ug+rw 0 0
```

The command instructs to mount the `processing` folder to the `incoming` folder, overriding the owner/group and assigning read + write permissions.

**Handle the file in your application**
Extract the `$request_body_file` from a header (e.g. `X-FILE` as illustrated the question). Then rewrite the `/var/local/incoming` parh to `/var/local/processing` and you can work with the files without any issues.

Comment: perfect works for me